Shopify Hydrogen install Error npm create @shopify/hydrogen@latest
enter image description here
I am trying to install shopify hydron but its gives error
Failed to initialize project: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'c:\Users\windows%2011\AppData\Local\npm-cache_npx\e1eac9  │
│  4ad41cc36f\node_modules@shopify\create-hydrogen\dist\assets\hydrogen\starter\app\root.tsx'

I don't think that's the image you meant to include

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
